# Node.js API with express & mysql - WHERE IN and bind parameter with mutliple comma seperated values

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

I have a url like this ... where multiple (comma seperated values can be added to the url)

```
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?title=mr,dr
```

That's my query:

```
router.get('/search?', function(req, res, next) {
    var title = req.query.title;

    var paramTitle = '\'' + title.split(',').join('\',\'') + '\''; 

    var setParams = [];
    if (title) {    
        setParams = [paramTitle];
    } 

    var sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE title IN (?)"; 

    connection.query(sql, setParams, function (error, results, fields) {
        res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
    });
});
```

But I get an Error:

```
sql "SELECT * from users WHERE title IN '(\\'mr\\',\\'dr\\')' LIMIT 100"
```

How can I get this:

```
var sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE title IN ('mr','dr')";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding is expecting an array, so you don't need to do the manual joining yourself.

```
var paramTitle = title.split(','); 

var setParams = [];
if (title) {    
    setParams = [paramTitle];
}
```